# How to set Java/Java SE stack setting on Azure webapp using powershell

Tags: java, azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to do the same as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46428009/how-to-set-the-java-tomcat-options-for-an-azure-web-app-using-azure-powershell). However I cannot get the Java container to change to Java SE. I have tried multiple keyword but none seem to work. Using the commands in the post I can change Tomcat versions but not from Tomcat to Java SE. What is the Java container value for Java SE? As well as Java container version for Java SE?

Answer (score 0):

You would use 'Jetty" as both the Java Container value and Java container version value.